# Define a reference in a range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I am totally new to C++, so the question may be a bit naive :D! Recently I have been confused by a question relating to declaration in the range-based for. We are allowed to write something like:

```
for(int &i : vec)
```

Then a confusion occurred. It seems to me, the variable *i* will be defined once and be assigned to different value in each loop. But in the case above, *i* is a reference which is just an alias and should be bound to only one object. I think one way to come around this is to think that a new *i* is defined each time. I searched for further explanation on this and found a page: [range for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)!:

---

Syntax attr(optional)

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

**Explanation**

The above syntax produces code similar to the following (__range, __begin and __end are for exposition only):

```
auto && __range = range_expression ;
for (auto __begin = begin_expr,

            __end = end_expr;

        __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
}
```

---

The 'range_declaration' is defined within for loop. But isn't a variable defined inside a loop reused which means the reference *i* defined in the first example is reused? Still I am confused and could any one please give me some hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable defined inside the loop body is local to the loop body and thus destroyed and re-defined each time the loop iterates. So the `int &i` is freshly initialised in each iteration and there's no problem.

It might be clearer if we perfrom the substitutions (with some simplifications) into the example you've posted:

```
for (auto b = begin(vec), e = end(vec); b != e; ++b) {
  int &i = *b;
  //loop statement
}
```

Comment: Hi Angew, thank you very much. I get it now. I think my misunderstanding lies in not to be clear about variables defined in a loop. I thought variables is defined once and will be reused later. To be certain, assume the for loop you wrote above has 10 iterations. In the first round, reference i is defined and after the closing curly brace is met, i is destroyed. Now in the second round, a new reference i is defined and will be discarded once the second round is finished. This pattern continues till the end. Have I got it right? Thanks!

Comment: @dylanG35 Yes, you got it right. You can easily verify this yourself by creating a class which does something observable (e.g. write to `std::cout`) in its constructor and destructor, and declaring a local variable of this class type inside the loop. You'll see the ctor and dtor are invoked in each iteration.